# Crystal Report 2008 Runtime Download

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

Could anyone please help me where I can download the Crystal Reports 2008 Runtime. I had a look at below:
http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/additional_downloads/runtime.asp#08

It says to download from below:
https://websmp130.sap-ag.de/sap%28bD1lbiZjPTAwMQ==%29/bc/bsp/spn/bobj_download/main.htm

I can't find any Crystal Reports 2008 Rutime download.

if anyone could help will be great

Answer (score 4):

The runtimes are now available here: http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-27917

Comment: Not available...!

Answer (score 4):

Use these URLs for the 2008 version (32 and 64 bit)

https://smpdl.sap-ag.de/~sapidp/012002523100009351342008E/CRBasicVS2008_redist_x86.zip

https://smpdl.sap-ag.de/~sapidp/012002523100009351332008E/CRBasicVS2008_redist_x64.zip

Comment: More important than the broken URLs, this answer is a [link-only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/284827) and as such, is liable to be deleted.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @WaiHaLee The links answer the question, so the problem is not the answer, but rather the question. Also, it's easy enough to fix the links instead of writing a comment, isn't it?

Comment: @ArtjomB. - looking at the question, I accept that you are right. Admittedly I could have edited the links myself, but I was reluctant to because it didn't resolve the link-only nature to the answer. However, as you point out, the question is the problem in this instance.